# Angular2 v2.4.9 HTML select doesn't show options

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this problem with angular2 since i was migrating from angularjs, 
the options data ofthe select element comes from a query from solr, this query doesn't take that long and always gives response 200 and the data.

The issues is that if i don't refresh the page or logout and login again, this select the options never appear, and sometimes is random the number of times i have to refresh to see those options.

i thought this issue had to do with bootstrap or the browser, but in chrome and firefox the issue is the same.

i think is an angular2 bug, but right now i'm looking for a work around or hack to make it work, i have to show the webpage working tomorrow (i hope).

html code:

```
    <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedId" (change)="changeValue($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let d of destinos | orderBy" [ngValue]="d.id">{{getName(d)}}</option>

</select>
```

**Additional details**:

- destinos data is being filled correctly, i can see the output when the data is received
- orderBy is a custom pipe, here is the code:

> import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
>
> @Pipe({ name: 'orderBy', pure: false })
>
> export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {   transform(array:
>   Array, args: string): Array {
>
> ```
> console.log(array);
> if (array == undefined)
>   return;
> array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
>
>   if (a.toLowerCase() < b.toLowerCase()) {
>     return -1;
>   } else if (a.toLowerCase() > b.toLowerCase()) {
>     return 1;
>   } else {
>
>     return 0;
>   }
> });
> return array;   }
> ```
>
> }

**update**
just in case anybody has this problem i removed the `class="selectpicker"` from  the select and now it works always, i think the problem it has to do with bootstrap, for now while looks a bit ugly it's good a temporal solution.

Comment: I believe your problem have nothing to do with that referenced bug. I would like to see your piece of code that fill "destinos" array.

Comment: Please give some more details to your problem

Comment: is orderBy a custom or default pipe? can be called with no arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without "| orderBy" ? 
because in Angular2, there is no more FilterPipe or OrderByPipe.
-> https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Comment: OrderBy is a custom pipe